# No MaterialLocalizations found. DatePickerDialog widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm using the function `showDatePicker` in my flutter app but when I switch locale it gives me this error :

```
No MaterialLocalizations found.

DatePickerDialog widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor.
The material library uses Localizations to generate messages, labels, and abbreviations.

To introduce a MaterialLocalizations, either use a MaterialApp at the root of your application to include them automatically, or add a Localization widget with a MaterialLocalizations delegate.
```

Here is my code :

```dart
  Future<void> selectDate() async {
    const MaterialColor(
      0xFF4A5BF6,
      const <int, Color>{
        50: const Color(0xff393e59),
        100: const Color(0xff393e59),
        200: const Color(0xff393e59),
        300: const Color(0xff393e59),
        400: const Color(0xff393e59),
        500: const Color(0xff393e59),
        600: const Color(0xff393e59),
        700: const Color(0xff393e59),
        800: const Color(0xff393e59),
        900: const Color(0xff393e59),
      },
    );
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      locale: Get.locale,
      context: Get.context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1800, 8),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: kFontSecondaryLightColor, // header background color
              onPrimary: Colors.white, // header text color
              onSurface: Colors.black, // body text color
            ),
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.red, // button text color
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      selectedDate = picked;
      birthdateTextController.text =
          "${picked.year} - ${picked.month} - ${picked.day}";
    }
  }
```

**NOTE**

I'm using `Getx` for flutter

Here is my `GetMaterialApp`:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(builder: (context, theme, child) {
        return GetMaterialApp(
          builder: (context, child) {
            return MediaQuery(
              child: child,
              data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
            );
          },
          translations: Messages(),
          // your translations
          locale: LanguageHelper().checkLanguage() == null
              ? Get.deviceLocale
              : LanguageHelper().checkLanguage() == "en"
                  ? Locale('en', 'US')
                  : Locale("ar", "AR"),
          fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'UK'),
          title: kAppName,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: themeData(context),
          darkTheme: darkThemeData(context),
          themeMode: theme.isLightTheme ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark,
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          defaultTransition: Transition.rightToLeftWithFade,
          initialRoute: AppPages.initial,
          getPages: AppPages.routes,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of the GetMaterialApp

Comment: @Gwnhyyy question updated

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the context you're using in the `showDatePicker` which is the `Get.context` doesn't have a `MaterialLocalizations`. `Getx` has it just to shut situations where it's necessary for the code to work, not for the overlay context.

from the [official docs](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/route-management/index/) :

> For all other Flutter dialog widgets, including cupertinos, you can use Get.overlayContext instead of context, and open it anywhere in your code. For widgets that don't use Overlay, you can use Get.context. These two contexts will work in 99% of cases to replace the context of your UI, except for cases where inheritedWidget is used without a navigation context.

so it should be fine just by using a `Get.overlayContext` instead of `Get.context` :

```
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
  locale: Get.locale,
  context: Get.overlayContext,
  initialDate: selectedDate,
  firstDate: DateTime(1800, 8),
  lastDate: DateTime(2101),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
          primary: kFontSecondaryLightColor, // header background color
          onPrimary: Colors.white, // header text color
          onSurface: Colors.black, // body text color
        ),
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.red, // button text color
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  },
);
```

this should work fine.

another solution :

in such cases using showDialog, showDateTimePicker, and showBottomSheet.., where the context may cause a problematic behavior. it's good to pass the context with functions, or constructors.. from the view to the controller where you call those methods :

View:

```
onPressed: () {
controller.showDialogFromController(context);
 }
```

Controller:

```
showDialogFromController(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(context) {
    /* your code*/
    }
    }
```